# Level Order Traversal of BST

Tags: c, tree

My program is not giving the desired output. Pls check. What I am doing is, I am first building the queue and then printing every node in the order mentioned in the queue.

The desired output should be F D J B E G K A C I H. The output I am getting is F D J B A C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

struct queue
{
    struct node *root;
    struct queue *next;
};

struct queue *head;

struct node* newnode(char c)
{
    struct node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->data = c;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    return n;
}

void enqueue(struct node *tree)
{
     if(head == NULL)
     {
        struct queue *n = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
        n->root = tree;
        n->next = NULL;
        head = n; 
     }
     else
     {
         struct queue *p = head;
         while(p->next != NULL)
         {
             p = p->next;
         }
         struct queue *n = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
         n->root = tree;
         n->next = NULL;
         p->next = n;
     }
}

void traverse(struct node *tree)
{
    if(tree != NULL)
    {
        enqueue(tree->left);
        enqueue(tree->right);
        traverse(tree->left);
        traverse(tree->right);
    }
}

void display()
{
    struct queue *p = head;
    while(p->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ",p->root->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("%c \n",p->root->data);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = newnode('F');
    root->left = newnode('D');
    root->right = newnode('J');
    root->left->left = newnode('B');
    root->left->right = newnode('E');
    root->right->left = newnode('G');
    root->right->right = newnode('K');
    root->left->left->left = newnode('A');
    root->left->left->right = newnode('C');
    root->right->left->left = newnode('I');
    root->right->left->left->right = newnode('H');
    enqueue(root);
    traverse(root);
    display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this `c`? Can you tag the programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues in the `traverse` function:

- `enqueue(tree->left)` will eventually add `NULL` to the queue, and this will cause problems in the `display` function, where it is expected that all `p` have a non-NULL `p->root` member.
- It doesn't perform a level by level traversal. It is more like a depth-first traversal (after traversing direct siblings). In a level order traversal, there is no recursion. You should iterate the queue (lagging behind as it grows), to fetch values for `tree`.

Here is a correction for `traverse`:

```c
void traverse(struct node *tree)
{
    struct queue *current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        tree = current->root;
        if (tree->left != NULL) enqueue(tree->left);
        if (tree->right != NULL) enqueue(tree->right);
        current = current->next; // Walk along the queue while it is being built
    }
}
```